# Generate multiple CSV files using macro from .xslm file

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have macro script that:

- Exports multiple csv files, using the "next" separator in column A, until the "stop" is found.
- Saves each csv file with name file from column S, corresponding row, "file 1", "file 2", "file 3"
- Column header in the top of the .xslm is copied for each exported .csv, so the .xlsm file does not need to have repeated headers in each row before “next”
- It does escape delimiters like “;”
- It export Unicode symbols
- It generate CSV file.

**I want the script to generate multiple files with same requirements as mentioned above.**

*Here is Macro Code:*

```
Sub export_multiple_CSV()
    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim wsCopyRange As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = CurrentWB.Sheets("File")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The 'File' sheet is missing!"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    Else
        lastRow = ws.UsedRange.rows.count
        Set wsCopyRange = ws.UsedRange
    End If

    ' Initialize variables
    Dim sRow As Long, eRow As Long
    Dim counter As Long: counter = 1
    Dim inSection As Boolean: inSection = False

    ' Loop through each row in column A
    For sRow = 1 To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(sRow, 1).value = "next" Then
            inSection = True
            eRow = sRow - 1
            ' Check if we are at the last row
            If sRow = lastRow Then
                eRow = lastRow
            End If
        ElseIf ws.Cells(sRow, 1).value = "stop" Then
            ' Check if we are in a section
            If inSection Then
                ' Create a temporary workbook and copy the range
                Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
                wsCopyRange.Offset(eRow).Resize(sRow - eRow).Copy
                With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    ' Replace add block here
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                ' Generate the filename from column S
                Dim fName As String: fName = ws.Cells(eRow, 19).value & "_file" & counter & ".csv"
                MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & fName

                ' Save the workbook as CSV with UTF-8 encoding
                TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
                'SaveAsUTF8 MyFileName

                TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
                counter = counter + 1
                inSection = False
            End If
        End If
    Next sRow

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

How can we modify this code to generate multiple files (we can specify how many file we want to generate).

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `corresponding row`. Is it a row which has `next` or `stop`?

Comment: Repeat the `TempWB.SaveAs ..`  line using a `For 1 to n: ... :Next` block that incudes incrementing the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close to finish. I have made some changes.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub export_multiple_CSV()
    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, ColCount As Long
    Dim wsCopyRange As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = CurrentWB.Sheets("File")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The 'File' sheet is missing!"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set wsCopyRange = ws.UsedRange
        ' Get rows # and columns #
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ColCount = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
    End If
    ' Initialize variables
    Dim sRow As Long, eRow As Long
    Dim counter As Long: counter = 0
    Dim inSection As Boolean: inSection = False
    ' Loop through each row in column A
    For sRow = 1 To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(sRow, 1).Value = "next" Then
            inSection = True
            eRow = sRow 
        ElseIf ws.Cells(sRow, 1).Value = "stop" Then
            ' Check if we are in a section
            If inSection Then
                ' Create a temporary workbook and copy the range
                Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
                ' Assign value is more efficient than copy / paste
                With TempWB.Sheets(1)
                    .Range("A1:A" & ColCount).Value = wsCopyRange.Range("A1:A" & ColCount).Value
                    .Range("A2").Resize(sRow - eRow - 1, ColCount).Value = wsCopyRange.Offset(eRow).Resize(sRow - eRow - 1, ColCount).Value
                End With
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                ' Generate the filename from column S (at "next" row) **modify as needed if filename is in other row
                Dim fName As String: fName = ws.Cells(eRow, 19).Value & "_file" & counter & ".csv"
                MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & fName
                ' Save the workbook as CSV with UTF-8 encoding, ** xlCSVUTF8 for UTF8 csv
                TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, CreateBackup:=False
                TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
                counter = counter + 1
                inSection = False
            End If
        End If
    Next sRow
    MsgBox "Export " & counter & " csv files."
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [XlFileFormat enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: does VBA recognizes the 'xlCSVUTF8'. As it says not declared variable when I run.

Comment: Yes. It's 62. _Microsoft documentation:_

> [XlFileFormat enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461). If you what to `save the workbook as CSV with UTF-8 encoding`, then you should use `FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8`. Did you run the code with Excel VBA?

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks, but the code you provided does not meet the requirements I mentioned above in question.

Comment: May I know which requirements? Would you mind share sample data in your post for testing?

Comment: I am not sure about data but these are the requirements:
Exports multiple csv files, using the "next" separator in column A, until the "stop" is found.
Column header in the top of the .xslm is copied for each exported .csv, so the .xlsm file does not need to have repeated headers in each row before “next”
It does escape delimiters like “;”
It export Unicode symbols

My above code is working fine for all requirements EXCEPT multiple files generate.

Comment: Still don't know the exact meaning of `does not meet the requirements`.